# Crystal Report Viewer is not loading in browser

Tags: asp.net, report, viewer

Anyone have any idea what is the issues above??
I am using Visual studio 2013 and Crystal Report v13.. I try to deploy it to local host(IIS) and broswer it, the Crystal Report is not loading unless I am using Fire Fox. I tried in Google Chrome, IE, Safari and also opera also not loading.

your comment is much appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem for finding resources when you are trying to access Crystal Report from local Internet Information Server in windows machine.
so for solution try to make the resource folder for crystal in your IIS directory as:

> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319\crystalreportviewers13

And Do Configuration in your Configuration file:

```
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="businessObjects">
  <sectionGroup name="crystalReports">
    <section name="rptBuildProvider" type="CrystalDecisions.Shared.RptBuildProviderHandler, CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, Custom=null" />
       <section name="crystalReportViewer" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
  </sectionGroup>
</sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

<businessObjects>
  <crystalReports>
    <rptBuildProvider>
      <add embedRptInResource="true" />
    </rptBuildProvider>
    <crystalReportViewer>
          <add key="ResourceUri" value="/crystalreportviewers13" />
  </crystalReportViewer>
  </crystalReports>
</businessObjects>
```

Hope this will help you to solve it.

Comment: It's not working... as @LstPatrick say, pointing to the section and throw me error.. cant even load the project...